# String Format method uniformity between 32/64-bit builds

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc, 64-bit

In my app (that can be built as both 32 and 64 bit with Visual Studio 2008) for one particular purpose I need to output the result into a debugging log. So I do this:

```
BOOL* pbBool = function1();

CString str;
str.Format(L"Line: pbBool=0x%I64X(%d)%s",
    pbBool,
    pbBool ? *pbBool : -1,
    bAddNewLine ? L"\n" : L""
    );
```

The code above works for 64-bit build but it crashes the app for a 32-bit build.

I'm assuming that the issue is in "%I64X", which I'm using because `pbBool` is 64-bit for a 64-bit build, and 32-bit for a 32-bit build. But I'm curious, is there a "uniform" specifier for the "format" function that can adjust automatically for this?

Comment: You can use `%p` to print a pointer.

Comment: Just use `I` instead of `I64`, it matches ptrdiff_t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- **Using `%I` to print a pointer** - you should use `%p` instead, and
- **Using `%s` to print a wide string** - you should use `%ls` instead

The modified format line should look like this:

```
L"Line: pbBool=0x%p(%d)%ls"
```

Comment: Thanks. Just from curiosity, where is a complete list of these for Visual Studio?

Comment: Also, did you mean to do "%p" instead of "%p64X"? And what is the difference between "%ls" and "%s"?

Comment: @c00000fd The complete list is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Be careful with Visual Studio, though - depending on the version of the compiler, the level of their compliance with the standard may vary.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I mean, there are many web sites for format specifiers but some don't work for VS. Still, am I missing from that page the difference between "%ls" and "%s" and why should I use the former?

Comment: @c00000fd The difference is reflected in the column to the right of `%s` - you have column headers "(none)" and "`l`".

Comment: Oh, thanks. I missed that. Although I don't think that it matters for VS. It works just fine with or without 'l'. "%p" makes a difference though.

Comment: And one last thing. I'm assuming that if I need to print a `HANDLE` I can use "%p" as well, can't I?

Comment: @c00000fd You should be able to print a handle after casting it to `void*`.